# ADF - Data flow limiting number of rows on group by

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a dataflow that reads data from an excel that has >100,000 rows.

I've added a **RowCount** column using a Surrogate Key:
[image]

I've then added another column called **BatchNumber** with the following expression, so that each row is assigned to a batch

```
ceil(RowNumber/$batchSize)
```

Then I've added a "group by" step using the BatchNumber value, so that the rows are grouped into batched of `$batchSize`.

My issue is that no matter what batch size I choose, the totals rows output is always 1,000. For example;

- Where `$batchSize = 100`, I get 10 batches of 100
- Where `$batchSize = 50`, I get 20 batches of 50

I've tried running the pipeline using the activity runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the limit is or where it is documented, but it appears the issue was when using the sink type **Cache**.
I changed it to a dataset and output the data to files and it exported everything I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

In Data factory Dataflow debug settings, there is `limit` to use how many rows are used to debug preview dataset. by default, it is of **1000 rows**. Only the number of rows you have specified as your limit in your debug settings will be queried by the data preview.

- Turn on Dataflow Debug and Click on debug settings.
  [image]
- Set the no of Row limit what you want. e.g. 100000 and Click on save.
  [image]

It will take that many rows in debug preview dataset. but in debug preview dataset it only shows 100 columns maximum.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this isn't the answer. Changing that setting, or running via the activity pipeline (not debug) has the same issue.